# Discord js bot caching issues

Tags: discord.js

Trying to fetch the list of users on a discord guild(server) but whenever I fetch the list it always returns 1 user that is the bot itself. Tried to execute

```
console.log(client.guilds.cache.get(config.SERVER_ID).members.cache.size)
console.log(client.guilds.cache.get(config.SERVER_ID).memberCount)
```

The first line returns 1 and second-line returns 420(number of users on discord server). I am not able to update the client's cache. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line is returning 1 since your bot is the only cached user on the server. Your second line returns the correct amount because `Guild.memberCount` doesn't need *any* users to be cached, it takes the data directly from the guild.

If you want to cache every member of a guild, you can use [`GuildMemberManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch).

```js
client.guilds.cache
 .get(config.SERVER_ID)
 .members.fetch()
 .then((members) => {
  console.log(members.size); // 420
  // code...
 });
```

Comment: It throws (node:4652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.

Comment: [None of my guilmember events are emitting and my functions are timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-and-my-functions-are-timin)

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I was missing the required intents