# Why is message.client.users.cache.random() only getting people that have messaged?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The command I set up just grabs a random user to spice up the message a bit. I had to fix something last night and when I restarted the bot, it is now only getting anyone that has messaged. Before, it was getting any random person in the server like it's supposed to. I have also tried to use

```
message.guild.members.cache.random();
```

with the same results. Here is the rest of the code from that command

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const colors = require('../../colors.json');

const candyAmount = require('../../candyheld.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: 'trickortreat',
    description: 'Special Halloween command',
    execute(message, args) {

        if (!candyAmount[message.author.id]) {
            candyAmount[message.author.id] = {
                candyStored: 5
            }
            
            fs.writeFile('./candyheld.json', JSON.stringify(candyAmount), err => {
                if (err) console.error(err);
            });
            
            message.delete();
            return message.channel.send('For starting the event, you have been given 5 pieces of candy!');
        }
        
        // Stores a random number of candy from 1-3
        let candyGiven = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
        let jackpot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 20 );
        let highJackpot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 200);

        let randomMember = message.client.users.cache.random();
        
        // Sets the possible messages to be received
        let trickortreatmessage = [
            'The scarecrow standing behind you jumps out at you and makes you drop all your candy!',
            `${randomMember} was nice enough to give you Candy! ${message.author} got ${candyGiven} pieces of candy!`,
            `Oh no! ${message.author} asked ${randomMember} for Candy and they decided to egg you instead!`,
            `The Headless Horseman rides and slashes his way to every bin of candy all just to give you everything he got!\n\n${message.author} got ${jackpot} Candy!`,
            `The wolves howl in sync as Candy rains from the sky! The adrenaline makes you move at lightning speed to grab every piece of Candy!\n\n ${message.author} got ${highJackpot} Candy!!!`
        ]

        // Store one of the random messages
        let trickortreat;
        let odds = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
        if (odds <= 25) trickortreat = trickortreatmessage[4]; // .5% chance
        else if (odds <= 49) trickortreat = trickortreatmessage[0]; // .5% chance
        else if (odds <= 499) trickortreat = trickortreatmessage[3]; // 9% chance
        else if (odds <= 1999) trickortreat = trickortreatmessage[2]; // 30% chance
        else trickortreat = trickortreatmessage[1]; // 60% chance

        if (trickortreat == trickortreatmessage[0]) {
            candyAmount[message.author.id].candyStored = 0;
        } else if (trickortreat == trickortreatmessage[1]) {
            candyAmount[message.author.id].candyStored += candyGiven;
        } else if (trickortreat == trickortreatmessage[3]) {
            candyAmount[message.author.id].candyStored += jackpot;
        } else if (trickortreat == trickortreatmessage[4]) {
            candyAmount[message.author.id].candyStored += highJackpot;
        }
        
        fs.writeFile('./candyheld.json', JSON.stringify(candyAmount), err => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
        });

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colors.serverRed)
        .addField('\u200B', `**${trickortreat}**`)

        message.delete();
        message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting and my functions are timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-and-my-functions-are-timin)

Comment: That has nothing to do with my concern

Comment: Yeah it does. Your user cache is starting empty, which has to do with intents.

Comment: It was working before last night perfectly fine, picking random people when I first introduced the command. Why would intents now be a problem. Again this doesn’t pertain to my issue

Comment: Again, it does. Discord just recently started enforcing the two intents outlined in the answer to the linked question. As recently as last night for some people such as yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that "message.guild.members.cache" starts empty even though I hadn't done any code changes related to it. It was due to changes made by Discord.

It is easy to fix though. You need to log in to the [Discord developer site > Applications](https://discord.com/developers/applications), choose your application/bot, got to the "Bot" tab, scroll down to "Privileged Gateway Intents" and tick off the "PRESENCE INTENT" and "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT
":

[image]

Note that if your bot is in 100 or more servers you need to whitelist it.

After that I restarted the bot and now it works fine again.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], and read [answer]. Don't include "I have the same problem" section as part of your answer. it is not helpful. The rest looks good ☺️