# How do I check if anyone in a guild has a role? discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want to be able to check if anyone in the whole server has a specific role. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Role.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members) returns a collection of every cached member who has the given role. Note: you will need to [update the required intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-and-my-functions-are-timin) to use this correctly.

```js
// get the role
const role = guild.roles.cache.get('role-id');

role.members.each((member) => console.log(`${member.username} has the role!`));
```

Comment: I get the error, undefined has the role (the code works but the role search did not work too well)

Comment: Did you enable the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent?

Comment: Not Sure, What is that? My code is this: 
```
var ms = require('ms');
var Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require("../config.json");

module.exports ={
    name: 'testing',
    description: `testing cmnd`,
    async execute(message, args, client) {
        var guild = message.guild;
        var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Admin");
        role.members.each((member) => console.log(`${member.username} has the role!`));
    }
};

```

Comment: Check the post I linked in my original answer.