# Sending a Message For Only One User

Tags: discord.js

I made a code in which he sends a message to people with a specific role, however, for some reason it is sending only to me, code below

```
canal.send(`||@everyone||`, embed).then(message => {
                                    message.react('748309940795473980')
                                })
                                servidor.roles.cache.get("771492474594000928").members.forEach((membro) => {
                                    console.log(membro.user.username)
                                    membro.send(`${membro}`, embed)
                                })
```

I would like you to help me with this, this command does the following functions:

Send Message to One Channel (Working)

Send Message to People with a Specific Position (Not Working, Just Send to Me)

As You Can See, I tried to put console.log, however, he was supposed to appear the name of everyone who received the message, but no, only my name appears, and only I get the message

I Need to Get This Working!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: Lioness100 Yes, Thank You So Much