# My discord server welcome message isn't working

Tags: discord.js

I've tried for a while but for some reason my Discord server welcome message isn't working. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.
Here's my code :

```
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
  const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'welcome')
  var serverIcon = message.guild.iconURL();
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Welcome!")
  .setColor(3447003)
  .setDescription(`Welcome <${member.user.username}> to ${guild.name}!`)
  .addField(
    { name: ':D', value: 'Hope you enjoy your stay!'}
  )
  .setFooter("© Ninjabot 2020", bot.user.avatarURL)
  .setThumbnail(serverIcon)
  .setTimestamp()
  welcomeChannel.send({embed});
  })
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting, if any?

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages

Comment: I believe your having the same problem as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica). I suggest checking that post first.

Comment: Okay so now I enabled Privelleged intents, I now recieve the error message saying that `var serverIcon = message.guild.iconURL();`
message isn't defined
guild isn't defined

Comment: yes, because you are in the `guildMemberAdd` event. You don't have access to a `message` object here. Change `message.guild.iconURL();` to `member.guild.iconURL();` and it should work.

Comment: Sorry hehe I'm newish to this. I changed it to member but now I'm getting this error message:
.setDescription(`Welcome <${member.user.username}> to ${guild.name}!`)
                                                          ^

ReferenceError: guild is not defined

Comment: same problem. You don't have a guild object here. You only have a member object.

Comment: How do I send the guild name then?

Comment: same as with the iconURL, You need to use the `member` object to get to the `guild` object. Please read the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now! Sorry I didn't check the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```js
welcomeChannel.send({embed});
```

with

```js
welcomeChannel.send(${embed});
```

or

```js
welcomeChannel.send(embed);
```

Example:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(i => i.name === 'Among The Server'))
    
    const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    
    welcomeEmbed.setColor('#5cf000')
    welcomeEmbed.setTitle('**' + member.user.username + '** is now Among Us other **' + member.guild.memberCount + '** people')
    welcomeEmbed.setImage('https://myurl')
    
    member.guild.channels.cache.find(i => i.name === 'greetings').send(welcomeEmbed)
});
```

Comment: Well when I do that it says , expected and if I do 
` welcomeChannel.send($,{embed});`
then it doesn't make any difference.
Now I'm going to try to do the embed without the 
`bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {`
  `const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'welcome')`
and see if the embed works.