# Role member count discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to get number of members with a role, but always give me "1":

```js
const server_roles = client.guilds.cache.get('server ID').roles.cache.get('role ID').members.size;

console.log(server_roles)
```

*Log:*

[image]

Real role member count = 4, not 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't within your code, it's to do with the information bots can access after a recent update. In order to fix this:

- Go to your Discord Developer Application page https://discord.com/developers/applications/
- Open your Discord bot application
- In the left side menu, select `Bot`
- Scroll down to `Privileged Gateway Intents`
- Turn both toggles on next to `PRESENCE INTENT` and `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`

Then, in the code, when initialising your Discord client, add this:

```
Discord.Client({ ws: { intents: Discord.Intents.ALL } });
```

That code assumes you've imported the module as `Discord`

It's quite complex, but after the recent update it's the only way to achieve what you want