# I am having problems with my member counting discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have used this code for counting my members on my discord server but then it suddenly stopped. I used the same code for a month or more and now I don't understand the problem. I have no errors or anything it just no longer counts the members when they join or leave.

```
let serverStats = {
    ServerId: '763432307863322645',
    totalUsersID: '764267842413264926',
    memberCountID: '764267939196043294',
    botCountID: '764268032637796402'
};


client.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{

    if (member.guild.id !== serverStats.ServerId) return;

    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.totalUsersID).setName(`Total Users: ${member.guild.memberCount}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.memberCountID).setName(`Members: ${member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.user.bot).size}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.botCountID).setName(`Bots: ${member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.user.bot).size}`);

});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', member =>{

    if (member.guild.id !== serverStats.ServerId) return;

    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.totalUsersID).setName(`Total Users: ${member.guild.memberCount}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.memberCountID).setName(`Members: ${member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.user.bot).size}`);
    client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.botCountID).setName(`Bots: ${member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.user.bot).size}`);

});
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `client.channels.cache.get(serverStats.[...])` inside the events to see if they are properly populated?

Comment: If it worked for a month or more, and it "suddenly stopped", without you changing anything at all, not one little thing no matter how insignificant you may think the change was, I'm not sure what you expect someone else to do - the only thing that looks out of place is `.size` - but that would've always been wrong (if it is wrong) anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the property `Guild#memberCount` ? It is supposed to return the number of members in your guild, so should meet your needs.