# How to make the collector check for users who have not written down in chat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Recently I started encountering a problem with the collector.
Basically, when I restart the bot, the collector doesn't collect the emojis from users unless the user has written down a random text in the channel. I found a solution creating a 'debug function' who simply delete the user debug command once he writes it, but this is far from a real fix.

node v15.0.1 & discord.js 12.4.1

Comment: Could you provide the collector code, or any code that doesn't appear to work. And this may be to do with Discords updated intents.

Comment: this is the collector code : 
`const collector = embedMessage.createReactionCollector(filter);
                collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {...})`
The same code was working fine a week ago, I'll check on discord.js updates if I can find something.

Comment: The intents update was rolled out just over a week ago, so I assume this is the problem. https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056426994

Comment: Having said this, I've managed to get a reaction collector working on my bot without intents. Seeing the entire collector may be useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed an issue with discord's Gateway update, you need to manually enable GUILD_PRESENCES on discord developer portal.

Thx a lot Ahsoka :)

the link answering the question :
https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056426994