# How to add a reaction role function with custom emojis?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello members of the Stack Overflow community,

I have been working on a function that activates when a moderator approves a user using Auttaja's gatekeeper. Basically, the new user gets to choose between two server emoji reactions, which will give him/her the roles. But I have been having difficulties with the role and emoji constants.

Here's my code:

```
 const ApprovalEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('RED')
.setTitle('Hi there new user!')
.setDescription('Please react to this message with either one of the emojis in order to get a role.')
.addFields(
  { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
  { name: 'The Boomer emoji gives you the "Les boomers normaux" role, and the rat emoji gives you the "The normal Rat Haven dwellers" role.'},
   { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
  { name: 'Selecting the Boomer emoji will give you access to only the Boomer Haven compartment, and the rat emoji will give you access to the Rat Haven compartment. '},
  { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
  {name: 'To get access to both of these compartments, please consider using the command "^AccessToBoth" to receive the "Access to both compartments" role.'},
  )
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter('Time to pick a role!');
  const roleOne = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "The normal Rat Haven dwellers")
  const roleTwo = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Les boomers normaux")
  const BoomerEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'boomer');
  const RatEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'robincutmoment');



client.on('message', async message => {
  let AdminRole = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Server Moderators")
  let RulerRole = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "The Supreme Boomers")
  let RatRole = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Rat Majesty Robin")
  if (message.member.roles.cache.has(AdminRole)) {
  } else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(RulerRole)) {
  } else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(RatRole)) {}
  if (message.content === `-approve`) {
    message.channel.send(BoomerEmoji)
    const reactionMessage = await message.channel.send(ApprovalEmbed);
    message.channel.send(ApprovalEmbed).then(reactionMessage.react(BoomerEmoji), reactionMessage.react(RatEmoji))
      
    
  }
  const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return [(BoomerEmoji), (RatEmoji)].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
  };
  message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
      const reaction = collected.first();
      
      if (reaction.emoji.name === (BoomerEmoji)) {
        message.member.roles.add(roleOne)
      } else if (reaction.emoji.name === (RatEmoji)) {
              message.member.roles.add(roleTwo)
      }
  })
```

});

Comment: "Having difficulties" is not enough for us to diagnose a problem and give a solution. What's currently going wrong? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi Lioness, I'm getting errors that indicate that the role constants aren't doing their thing when the user clicks on the reaction. The same thing can also be said for the reactions. They just don't show up.

Comment: Do you have [both intents enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)?

Comment: Yes I do. All intents are enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is occurring in this snippet:

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.has(AdminRole)) {
 // ...
} else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(RulerRole)) {
 // ...
} else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(RatRole)) {
 // ...
}
```

[`Collection.prototype.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) checks if an element exists in the collection. It takes one parameter: the *key* of the element you wish to check the existence of. Since [roles](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) are mapped by [snowflakes](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake), you should be passing the [role ID](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=id), not the [entire object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role).

```js
// `Collection.prototype.has()` is identical to `Map.prototype.has()`
// here's how it works:
const map = new Map();

// 'foo' is the key,
// 'bar' is the value
map.set('foo', 'bar');

console.log(map.has('foo')); // true
console.log(map.has('bar')); // 'bar' is not the key; false
```

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.has(AdminRole.id)) {
 // ...
} else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(RulerRole.id)) {
 // ...
} else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(RatRole.id)) {
 // ...
}
```

If you'd like to be fancy, you could use [`Collection.prototype.findKey()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=findKey) instead of the normal [`Collection.prototype.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find). This method is almost the same, except it returns the key of the found element instead of the value. Again, it makes almost no difference; just another option.

```js
let AdminRole = message.member.roles.cache.findKey(
 (role) => role.name === 'Server Moderators'
);
let RulerRole = message.member.roles.cache.findKey(
 (role) => role.name === 'The Supreme Boomers'
);
let RatRole = message.member.roles.cache.findKey(
 (role) => role.name === 'Rat Majesty Robin'
);
if (message.member.roles.cache.has(AdminRole)) {
 // ...
} else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(RulerRole)) {
 // ...
} else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(RatRole)) {
 // ...
}
```

---

Your second problem is somewhat along the same lines. `BoomerEmoji` and `RatEmoji` are complete [`GuildEmoji`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmoji) objects. However, in this line:

```js
return (
 [BoomerEmoji, RatEmoji].includes(reaction.emoji.name) &&
 user.id === message.author.id
);
```

And these lines:

```js
if (reaction.emoji.name === BoomerEmoji) {
 message.member.roles.add(roleOne);
} else if (reaction.emoji.name === RatEmoji) {
 message.member.roles.add(roleTwo);
}
```

You're comparing it to the *name* property of another emoji. This fix is fairly simple, just clarify you only need the `name` properties when declaring each variable:

```js
const BoomerEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(
 (emoji) => emoji.name === 'boomer'
).name;
const RatEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(
 (emoji) => emoji.name === 'robincutmoment'
).name;
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help! However, there is a slight issue which includes the last part of the script, where the bot is supposed to give the user the role. I still cannot figure that out.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what that issue is?

Comment: Basically, where the bot gives the user the role (if (reaction.emoji.name === (BoomerEmoji)) {
        message.member.roles.add(roleOne)
      } else if (reaction.emoji.name === (RatEmoji)) {
              message.member.roles.add(roleTwo)
      } )

It doesn't do anything. It's just that the user clicks on the reaction, but he or she is not given the role.