# Javascript: Presence status is always offline

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Every time I am logging presence from the author that sends the message it is returning offline as their status. I know it is supposed to return 'idle', 'offline' or 'online'. I have switched my status on discord to all different ones and it always returns as offline. Also, I am assuming that since I am considered offline that's why the `clientStatus` returns null. I am trying to detect if the user is on a mobile device or not. It was working fine last week and now not working. Even my friend when he types !help it is logging him as offline Any help on how to fix this issue would be awesome.

```
else if (message.content === '!help') {
      console.log(message.author.presence)
      console.log(message.author.presence.clientStatus)
}

[![Console Log][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtQMs.png
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: enable your presence intents in Discord Developer Portal