# Bot not DMing the user when he joins

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Why is the bot not messaging the user when he joins the server?

```js
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription(`Willkommen bei ${colours.mainname}. Wir m`).setColor(colours.maincolour);
    member.send(embed);

    // var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '746850263335305316');
    // member.roles.add(role);
});
```

Comment: Please check out this question: [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390).

Comment: It doesnt help me...

Comment: Did you enable both of the intents?

Comment: Wdym with intents?

Comment: You said that it didn't help you but looks like you didn't even read the link

Comment: Now that you already know that intents might be the issue, you should also know that you're not catching the error on the `.send()` method. Some people have their DMs closed and using that send method on them will throw an error. To fix that you need to call catch after it. `.send().catch(err => console.log(err))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Jakye, you now must use intents. On the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers), select your project, and under bot tab, you'll need to tick the intents. Note it's more complicated for bots in over 100 guilds, but from what I've seen I don't think you're near that yet.
[image: You'll need to opt into intents]