# Discord.js | Welcome message doesn't react, send notification

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member, message) => {
    let replies = [`${member} Nepyk, ginklus paliekame prie durų! `, `${member} Žinok, pas mus Išėjimas ne išeitis! `, `${member} Aš tavimi didžiuojuosi!`, `${member}, Sveikas atvykęs į mūsų šeimynėlę!`, `${member} Ši vieta nebuvo tokia, kokia ją tu padarysi!`, `${member} atėjo pas mus pasitrinti!`, `${member} Pasiruošiau diržą, vien tik tau! ❤️`, `${member} Klausyk tėvų, arba bus bėdų! `, `${member} Ei! Viešoj vietoj nesikeikiam!`, `${member} Man rodos, tuoj tu gausi šluotą į rankas!`, `${member} Linksmai pasibūk!`, `${member} Atvyko iš Narnijos!`, `${member}, Žinok, kad man patinka mandarinai!`, `${member} Nebūk kiaušiniukas, pasakyk Labas!`, `${member} Aš būsiu tavo robotukas!`, `${member}, bus kaip visi... Laukinis!`, `Veidrodėli, Veidrodėli, kas pasaulyje gražiausias? ${member} `, `${member}, Aš negaliu, tiesiog negaliu!`, `${member}, Bus, Bus, Rožinis Dangus! `, `${member}, ar nori būti mano Romeo?`];
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('749656673374961774').send(replies[random]).then(msg => {
    msg.delete({timeout:10000})
})})
```

Discord.js | Welcome message doesn't react, send notification

I don't know why, but welcome commands don't work anymore.
Please help, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 1):

To use the `guldMemberAdd` event, you now need to enable the server members gateway intent in the bot section in the discord developer portal. Also, guildMemberAdd does not return a message, only a member. In addition to this, you probably don't want to include the entire member object in the welcome message. To mention the new member, you can do `${member.toString()}`.

Comment: GuildMember toString() automatically transforms it into <@id>

Comment: Any additional reason why it was downvoted? I believe that answer is correct, for I was having the same issue and that's how I fixed it.

Comment: You know that  `\`${member}\`` is the same as `member.toString()`