# is there an error in the const member for the displayName not working?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

the displayName was working perfectly for a few days, but now it is no longer working ... has anything changed in discord.js?

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || 
message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.displayName === args[0]);
```

Comment: the was a change made to cached objects. see if this helps you, [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: You need to enable presence intents in order to download the complete member list. Go to Discord Developer Portal and under privileged intents enable guild members