# Discord.js Bot Welcomes Member, Assign a Role and send them a DM

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, roles

So When A New Member Joins The `Guild` [the discord server]. The Bot Should Send A Message In a certain Channel (ID = 766716351007686696), Send Them A Direct Message, And Then Add A Role (Human Bean). This Is The code I Have Now and it isn't working, error at the bottom

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{
    const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === "766716351007686696")
    const channelwelcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ffd6d6')
        .setTitle('Welcome!')
        .setDescription(`${member} just joined the discord! Make sure to read #rules!`)
        .setTimestamp();
    channel.send(channelwelcomeEmbed);
    const dmwelcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ffd6d6')
        .setTitle('Welcome!')
        .setDescription("For Help Using @Pro Bot#7903, Send The Command `!help` In Server")
        .setTimestamp();
    member.send(dmwelcomeEmbed);
    let role6 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Human Bean"); //BASIC ROLE, EVERYONE GETS IT
    if(!role6) return message.reply("Couldn't find that Role .")
    member.roles.add(role6);
});
```

Error Message is;

```
    const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === "766716351007686696")
                    ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine, the problem is that the event isn't triggered. Thats because discord turned off "privileged intents" by default.

Some intents are defined as "Privileged" due to the sensitive nature of the data. Those intents are:

- `GUILD_PRESENCES`
- `GUILD_MEMBERS`

One effect of that is what you are experiencing, the not working `guildMemberAdd` event.

The good news is that you can fix this with one easy step. Simply enable **Privileged Gateway Intents** in the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and it should work just fine.

[image]

#### If you want to read more about it

- [Discord.js Official Guide - Gateway Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents)
- [Discord Developer Documentation - Gateway Intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents)
- [Gateway Update FAQ](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056426994)
- [Discord API Github - Issue 1363 - Priviledged Intents](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1363)
- [Discord Blog - The Future of Bots on Discord](https://blog.discord.com/the-future-of-bots-on-discord-4e6e050ab52e)
- [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: Okay, Now The Event Is Triggered. But An error Comes Up, See Bottom Of The Post For Details

Comment: yes, you don't access to message in this event. Change `message` to `member`. And you also can't reply in the event. If `role6` doesn't exist, just return.

Answer (score 1):

Fix: `const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID')`

You need to use `member` instead of `message`. Because `guildMemberAdd` function using `member`.

`client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {`