# For some reason my bot doesn't work when a new member joins my guild

Tags: javascript, discord.js, glitch-framework

For some reason, my bot doesn't work when a new member joins my guild. I specifically put a detection in the console so when someone joins the guild the console logs it. Yet I don't see anything in the console when I rejoin the server over and over again.

```
Bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  console.log("new member!");
  var Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("New member, " + member.user.name + "!")
    .setDescription()
    .setColor("#0099ff")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter()
    .setImage()
    .setThumbnail();

  Bot.channels.cache.get("773416484314939403").send(Embed);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the bot is running? There could be a token mismatch if the event doesn't fire

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)