# Making a welcome message in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm a starting developer in discord.js, and recently attempted at making welcome messages.

Could you help me, please?

```
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    console.log(member)
    const message = `Hello <@${member.id}>`

    const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.get('775672625018961940')

    welcomeChannel.send(message)
  })
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Add it to your question. Explain the problem.

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages.
Code doesn't seem to interrupt my code and no problems show up.

Only issue is that no messages are sent to the channel.

Comment: so there is nothing from the `console.log(member)` either?

Comment: Nope. Nothing seems to appear either in the console nor in the discord server.

Comment: See if this answers your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just sharing the same answer from Worthy Alpaca.

This is so that people who are googling can see the answer.

This may answer your question: [Discord.js Bot Welcomes Member, Assign a Role and send them a DM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684)

Good luck with the rest of your bot and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You must enable intents. See more here: https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056426994