# Why does client.users.cache only show 2 users discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

For a server of mine, I need my bot to DM everyone at regular periods of time. I use

```js
client.users.cache.get(args[1]).send(toSend);
```

to do this, where `args[1]` contains the user's id and `toSend` is the message to send. However, it just turns up `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`. Then I tried logging `client.users.cache` to the console and it appears that only 2 users are in it, the bot itself and me. Why is this so, given that the server has at least 30 users?

Comment: see if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca Oh wow, that simple. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js Bot Welcomes Member, Assign a Role and send them a DM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)