# Discord.js: Why is it not counting members correctly?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Why is it not counting members correctly? (Also not a complete list of participants with names.)

```
console.log(`Number of participants on the server: ${msg.guild.members.cache.size}`)
msg.guild.members.cache.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.user.username)
});
```

[Look at the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUuyo.jpg)

Comment: Maybe there are other conditions to check the active users or those user's data is not in the cache, can you check the code? with the provided information, it's not possible for us to help you, you need to update the question.

Comment: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684) solves your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js Bot Welcomes Member, Assign a Role and send them a DM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm)