# Cannot access to user.presence.activities in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, user-presence, user-activity

I am coding a discord.js bot, and I'm trying to **get the activity of an user** (games he is playing, spotify things, etc.).

When I take a look at the documentation, I see a `Presence` class, and a `.activities` property, that is supposed to return an array of the user's activities.

However, I get the "Cannot send empty message" when I run my code, **with an activity running**.

Here is my actual code:

```
let member = message.users.mention.first || message.author;

message.channel.send(member.presence.activities);
```

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(member.presence.activities)` to see if the member actually has an activity?

Comment: Yes. it is returning an empty array, even if I have an activity displayed on discord...

Comment: that looks like an issue with privileged intents. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684) helps you

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the user has no activity and so the `member.presence.activities` returns null, therefore resulting in the `empty message` error.

To catch this, it is simple:

```js
let member = message.users.mention.first || message.author;

let memberActivies = member.presence.activities;
if (!memberActivities) return message.channel.send(':x: User has no activity set'); 

message.channel.send(memberActivities); //sends the activities
```

Also, if the `activities` param is an array, surely you would have to select from the array using the normal syntax `arr[0]` for example?

Comment: I already tried to console.log(memberActivities), but it's not returning 'user has no activity set', and it's still giving the 'cannot send empty message'. I really don't know what's wrong.