# (Closed) Discord bot welcome message and leave message not working

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.net

This is the welcome message and leave message I have set up with my discord bot. It is currently not working. It is not sending any errors. If you can help me out It would be appreciated. This is one of the bugs that I have not been able to fix. It may just be a simple error that I have made.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{
    const welcomemessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#0099ff")
        .setDescription(`Welcome <@${member.user.id}> to the server! Please take the time to read <#758441509371641866> and <#758441426807423056>`);
    message.guild.member.cache.get(user.id).then(function(){
        let userjoinchat = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name === "welcome");
        userjoinchat.send(welcomemessage);
    })
})
client.on('guildMemberRemove', member =>{
    const byemessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#0099ff")
        .setDescription(`Bye <@${member.user.id}>, I hope you enjoyed your stay!`);
    message.guild.member.cache.get(user.id).then(function(){
        let userleavechat = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name === "bye");
        userleavechat.send(byemessage);
    })
})
```

Comment: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684) answers your question

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca I have already turned that on, it may take a few hours or something to syn.

Comment: no it shouldn't. you need to restart the bot

Comment: I have already done that, and it still dose not work.

Comment: I just noticed something in your code. Do you per chance get an error about `message` not being defined?

Comment: I do not get any errors when the code is ran. It dose not look like message is defined. I did not think it needs to be. What would I define it as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you try to access the `message` object. The problem is that there is no message in the events you're using. Fortunatly that is an easy fix to make. All you have to do is access the `member` object, to which you do have access, instead.

I corrected your code here. I also stripped a few unneeded lines and added an extra check so you won't get an error if the channel cannot be found.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log("someone joined");
    const welcomemessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#0099ff")
        .setDescription(`Welcome ${member} to the server! Please take the time to read <#758441509371641866> and <#758441426807423056>`);
    
    let userjoinchat = member.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name === "welcome");
    if (!userjoinchat) return;
    userjoinchat.send(welcomemessage);
})
client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
    console.log("someone left");
    const byemessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#0099ff")
        .setDescription(`Bye ${member}, I hope you enjoyed your stay!`);

    let userleavechat = member.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name === "bye");
    if (!userleavechat) return;
    userleavechat.send(byemessage);
})
```

I have also added a `console.log()` at the beginning of each event, just so you can make sure they are actually emitting when someone joins or leaves. If thats not the case make sure you enable ["privileged intents"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684) in your bot developer settings.