# discord bot is not sending welcome massage

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to send a welcome message to a new user but the code doesn't work. I tried defiant articles and video tutorials and already asked questions for help but it's not working. I already checked ( Privileged Gateway Intents > PRESENCE INTENT ) and ( Privileged Gateway Intents > SERVER MEMBERS INTENT ) [here](https://ibb.co/j562MxG)

here's my code

```
// Instantiate a new client with some necessary parameters.
const client = new Client(
    { intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] }
)

const channelId = "969129834682929212";
  const rulesChannel = "969129988299304960";
  client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    console.log(member);

    const message = `Welcome <@${
      member.id
    }> to our server! Be sure to check out our ${member.guild.channels.cache
      .get(rulesChannel)
      .toString()}`;

    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);
    channel.send(message);
  });
```

Comment: You need to add the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent as well when you are creating your client.

Comment: Thanks @Caladan I'm missing GUILD_MEMBERS

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing this issue is because of recent gateway changes of the Discord Api that you need to enable the intents. Here is a fix for you –

- Head over to [Discord Developers Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/)
- Choose your application
- Inside the `bot` section if you scroll a little bit down , you will see a section named `Privileged Gateway Intents`
- Enable the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` and restart the bot and your bot will start recieving the `guildMemberAdd` event!

Learn more about intents at [Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)

Comment: (https://ibb.co/j562MxG) I already enable the options

Comment: and im also creating the Instantiate of new client with some necessary parameters
`const client = new Client(
    { intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] }
)`

Comment: This is most likely a privileged intents problem. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739350/discord-js-bot-welcomes-member-assign-a-role-and-send-them-a-dm/64739684#64739684) to see if it solves it.