# Discord.js greeting message has stopped working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I've had a bot working for my discord server for a while now and it worked perfectly, but suddenly one day it stopped sending the greeting messages. I don't know why it has happened, but I've tried everything I can and nothing works.

The console displays no error and no message is sent to the channel.

Here's the code:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'greeting-channel');
    if (!channel) return;
    channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!`);
});
```

Please, help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: You need to turn on intents in the Dev Portal to get this event from now on.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try, Thank you!