# When I react to the message my discord bot sent, it is not being picked up until I've interacted in the discord server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a ticket bot and it sends a message upon startup, but once the message has been sent, nothing happens when I react to it until I've done something like send a message in the discord server.  I am using Discord.JS.

I want to know if there is any possible way to cache the message or something so that I do not have to interact with the server for the reaction event to pick up my reaction.

My Startup Code:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`[AUTH] Authenticated with discord!`);

        client.guilds.cache.forEach(async function(dguild) {

            let channel1 = dguild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'new-ticket')
        
            if(!channel1) {
                await dguild.createChannel("actions", { type: 'text' })
                channel1 = dguild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'new-ticket')
            }
                
            const fetched1 = await channel1.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 });
            channel1.bulkDelete(fetched1);


            let departments1 = "";
            departments(deps => deps.forEach(dep => departments1 += '``'+dep.reactionEmoji +' '+ dep.name + '`` :: ' + dep.description + '\n\n'));

            let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(nte.title)
                .setColor(nte.color)
                .addField("\u200B", nte.header)
                .addField("Departments: \n", departments1)
                .addField("\u200B", nte.footer);

            channel1.send(embed1).then(async m => {
                await departments(deps => deps.forEach(dep => m.react(dep.reactionEmoji)));
                console.log(m.id +":"+channel1.id);
                dguild.channels.cache.get(channel1.id).message.cache.get(m.id);
            })
        });
});
```

My Reaction Event:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if(user.id == client.user.id) return;
    const userReactions = reaction.message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(user.id));
    try {
        for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
            await reaction.users.remove(user.id);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to remove reactions.');
    }

    departments(deps => deps.forEach(dep => {
        if (reaction.emoji.name == dep.reactionEmoji) {

            try {
                ticket.create(user.id, dep.id, reaction.message);
                console.log(dep.name + ":  Ticket Opened");
            } catch {
                console.log('Failed to generate ticket.');
            }

        }
    }))
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: do you have `Privileged Intents` enabled?

Comment: I feel really stupid now.  I didn't have that on and I completely forgot bout it :cry:

Comment: does it work once you enable that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)