# Discord bot not sending message in default channel when joining the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Here's the code:

```
FUNAI.on('guildCreate', joinedGuild => {
joinedGuild.send(`Hello ${joinedGuild.guild.name}!`) 
});
```

I've tried everything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: Unfortunately..nope.

Comment: you can't just send a message into a guild. You need to define a channel to send it in. Do you not get any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to send a message to a guild/server, which is not possible. However, you can try to send it to the #general channel if it exists (since Discord has removed the default channel function in 2017) :

```
const getDefaultChannel = (guild) => {
  // Check for a "general" channel, which is often default chat
  const generalChannel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "general");
  if (generalChannel)
    return generalChannel;
}

FUNAI.on('guildCreate', joinedGuild => {
  var defChannel = getDefaultChannel(joinedGuild);
  console.log(joinedGuild)
  if (defChannel) defChannel.send(`Hello ${joinedGuild.name}!`)
});
```

Comment: Long not defined.

Comment: Sorry, you need to do `npm install long` (on cmd) and then add at the top of your program `var Long = require("long");` to use the code.

Comment: it says nothing

Comment: I think it has do do with your discord.js version and unfortunatly I can't test them all now, but I edited my answer with a simplified version that get only the #general channel if it exists. It should work with a maximum of versions.