# How to trigger a block of code when a user joins a guild

Tags: discord.js

I've made a bot with discord.js and I want to run some code when a user joins my guild. The obvious answer here is the client event `guildMemberAdd`, which worked until about a month ago. For some odd reason it stopped working and I've been trying to fix it, but I have no idea what the problem is.

Here is a super simplified version of my script since it's over 3000 lines long:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log(`${member.user.tag} joined`);
});
```

I've even tried a try and catch block but everything seems fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They changed it so you have to go on the developer portal, click on your bot en turn Privileged Gateway Intents on then it should work again (it is in the bot tab)