# How can i make my inrole command cache every member in the guild

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i'm making a command that outputs every user in a role

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'in-role',
    description: 'Find all users in a specified role.',
    aliases: ['inrole'],
    async execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[0])

        if (role) {
            const roleMembers = role.members.map(member => member.toString())
            const inRoleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(role.name)
                .setDescription(roleMembers.join('\n'))
                .setColor(role.hexColor);

            message.channel.send(inRoleEmbed).catch(error => {
                message.channel.send('There was an error executing the command.')
                console.log(error)

            })
        }

    }

};
```

heres the code, it's only caching the top/first 2 members in the guild. Wondering if there is a way to make it get every member and then output all of the users in that role instead of only looking at top 2 members.

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only getting 2 members in your cache, it seems you haven't yet enabled privileged intents. [Find out how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica).

However, even after enabling intents, you still probably won't have every member of your guild cached, which is when you should use [`GuildMemberManager#fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch)

```js
// make sure you make your `execute` function async!

await guild.members.fetch();
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[0]);

...
```