# Event Member Role Update

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roles, member

**I'm trying to make an event that when someone gives a position to another member or places the position on himself with the administrator's permission, the bot will recognize and punish the member**

*(but it is not acknowledging or activating the event when executed and there is also no error on the console)...*

```
const { Listener } = require("..")
const { RichEmbed, Permissions } = require("discord.js")

let AntiRaidPerm = [
  'ADMINISTRATOR',
  'KICK_MEMBERS',
  'BAN_MEMBERS',
  'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
  'MANAGE_ROLES',
  'MANAGE_EMOJIS',
  'MANAGE_GUILD'
]
module.exports = class MemberRoleUpdate extends Listener {
  constructor (client) {
    super(client)
    this.events = {
      memberRoleUpdate: this.memberroleupdate
    }
  }

  async memberroleupdate (role) {
    if (!this.client.db || !this.client.db.mongoose.connection) return
    if (!role.guild || !role.guild.id) return

    let doc = await this.client.db.guilds.get(role.guild.id)

    const fetchedLogs = await role.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
      limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE',
    });

    const RoleLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();

    const { executor, target } = RoleLog;
    
    if( executor.id === this.client.user.id ) return;
    if(executor.id === role.guild.owner) return;

    const adminPerm = new Permissions(target.permissions)
    const adminremove = role.guild.roles.get(target.id)

    if(adminPerm.has('ADMINISTRATOR') === true) {
      const docban = await this.client.db.usersban.get(executor.id)
  
      docban.ban.name = executor.tag
      docban.ban.id = executor.id
  
      docban.ban.counta = docban.ban.counta +1
  
      await docban.save()
  
      let count1 = `${docban.ban.counta}`
      let limit = `${doc.antiraid.alimit}`
      let msg = "Anti-Raid ativado! O usuário {member}"
      const newMsg = msg.replace("{member}", executor.tag);
  
      let warnEmbed = new RichEmbed()
          .setColor("#f7002c")
          .setDescription(newMsg + " foi banido!");

        if(count1 >= limit) {

          role.guild.member(executor).ban(`Proteção de Cargos ativada - \'${executor.username}\' foi banido!`).then(async msg => {
            role.guild.channels.get(doc.antiraid.antilog).send(warnEmbed).catch(()=>{})

            console.log('Estou banindo')

            const perm = new Permissions(adminremove.permissions);
            adminremove.setPermissions(perm.remove('ADMINISTRATOR', ))

            role.guild.roles.forEach(async(role) => {
              let botrole = role.guild.roles.find("name", "The Anti Raiding")

                if(role.position === botrole.position) return;
                if(role.position > botrole.position) return;
          
              if (role.hasPermissions(AntiRaidPerm)) {

              role.setPermissions(perm.remove(AntiRaidPerm))
            }})
          }).catch(console.error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### New Gateway Intents

Last year, on October 27, 2020, Discord implemented new gateway intent restrictions, which resulted in issues fetching events that included the `GUILD_MEMBER` intent. A full explanation by [Lioness100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13721990) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica). In layman's terms, you haven't opted in to the proper intents, meaning your Discord bot will not receive certain events, such as [`guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate), which is what you want to have

### Solution?

To receive these events, you'll need to turn them on via the Discord Developer Portal. To do this, go to https://discord.com/developers/applications and find your application. Typically, your bot's username is the application's name. After selecting the application, go to the "Bot" tab on the right sidebar and scroll down to **Privileged Gateway Intents**. Tick the two boxes, as shown below, then tap "Save Changes." Your bot should be receiving the events
[image: Privileged Gateway Intents]