# How can I select a random user from a server?

Tags: discord.js

I'm using discord.js version 12, the problem is that the bot is only selecting 2 users out of the entire server (The author of the message and the bot) and I want it to be able to pick anybody from the server.

Here's the code that I've tried:

```
client.on('message', msg=>{
  if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === "!sru"){
    const randomUser = msg.guild.members.cache.random();
    msg.channel.send(`${randomUser.user.username}#${randomUser.user.discriminator}`);
  }
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the size of the Guild's members cache? `guild.members.cache.size`

Comment: @Jakye The server has 5 members, but the bot shows 2 unless another user gets pinged or sends a message.

Comment: @AnimatingCoder this is because of the requirement to cache users, so if they have sent no message they are not cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
client.on('message', msg=>{
  if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === "!sru"){
    const randomUser = msg.guild.members.cache.random();
   msg.channel.send(`${randomUser.user.username}#${randomUser.user.discriminator}`);
  }
})
```

Make sure you have your `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) activated.

Applications -> Bot -> Server Members Intent

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. The bot still only selects 2 people.

Comment: @AnimatingCoder maybe you deleted not everything from your old code or something like this. The code in my answer works without problems.

Comment: @AnimatingCoder remove your old code and replace it with my answers code.

Comment: This is happening because the other users are not cached, try and get the users to send messages in order to cache them. Sometimes it takes a little while in a new server

Comment: After you've enabled the intents in the developer portal you also need to use them when configuring the client. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390) should help you.

Comment: @Jakye Yes, that worked. Apparently I forgot to change `const client = new Discord.Client();` to `const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { intents: new Discord.Intents(Discord.Intents.ALL) }});`. Thanks for the help.