# Discord.js bot doesn't assign roles to new members

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

For some reason, the bot I wrote using Node.js and Discord.js does not assign roles to members when they join. Can someone please help?

```js
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", function (member) {
    member.guild.channels
        .find("name", "general")
        .send(
            member.toString() +
                " Welcome to the server. All your base are belong to us."
        );
    member.add(member.guild.roles.find("name", "Honorable Member"));
});
```

I've tried both `member.add` and `member.addRole`, nothing I do seems to have any effect. I'm not even getting an error message of any kind, the code just doesn't seem to be executing.

Comment: Are you using discord.js v12 or v11?

Comment: I'm using discord.js v11.6.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: @Zsolt Meszaros Yes!! That worked for me, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### How to figure out what discord.js version you have:

Open up Command Prompt in the current directory (the same folder as your bot.js file).
Then within that type `npm list discord.js` and it will return something similar to this:
[image: example of npm list command]

It will either start with 11 or 12, that is how you can tell if your discord.js is version 11 or version 12.

### How to fix your problem on discord.js v11:

Since you may be using discord.js v11, I'll give an example on how to fix it there:

```js
member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name", "Honorable Member").id);
```

### If you are using discord.js v12:

You need to use modern techniques to accomplish this.

```js
const roleToAdd = member.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Honorable Member");
member.roles.add(roleToAdd);
```

Comment: I'm using version 11.6.4, tried both options and neither made a difference. The bot doesn't do anything at all when a person joins a server, not even with a console.log command

Comment: I eventually managed to fix it, I had to enable some settings in the Discord Application portal and then your code worked for me. Thank you!