# Checking what device a user is on in Discord with Bot - Discord.JS

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have been looking for a little while to find how to check what device a user is on in Discord with my bot.

for example, if a person initiates the command "device" if they're on a phone it will return with "phone".

I found a method to do this but don't know how to use it, its Docs are [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=clientStatus).

If someone can explain this to me that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access [`Presence#clientStatus`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=clientStatus) through a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=presence) or [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=presence). This means that you can use [`Message#author#presence#clientStatus`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) to get the information from the author of the command.

Beware that this property will be `null` if you have not enabled the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)). From there it returns an object with the potential properties `web`, `mobile`, and `desktop` (none of these are guaranteed). For example, if I'm on the discord mobile app and desktop app, it would show:

```js
{
  desktop: 'online',
  mobile: 'online'
}
```

The value per property could either be `online`, `idle`, or `dnd`. More examples:

- I'm offline

```
{}
```

- I'm currently on the Discord website but I left the room so now I'm using Discord on my phone

```js
{
  web: 'idle',
  mobile: 'online',
}
```

- I'm trying to do homework so I don't want anyone to ping me but I keep procrastinating and looking at Discord

```js
{
  web: 'dnd',
  desktop: 'dnd',
  mobile: 'dnd',
}
```