# Discord.js How to check if there is user on server from id_blacklist array by id?

Tags: discord.js

I'm making some security stuff and i need blackist for user that was destroying my server and left so i cant ban them.

```
Here is code:

    var id_blacklist = ["some","user","id-s"]
    })
    setInterval(function(){ 
        checkUsers() 
    }, 5000);
    
    function checkUsers(){

  //here check if there is a user id that is on blacklist
}
```

EDIT: I mean to check users every 5 secconds. Because memberGuildAdd not working for no reason in my bot

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a setInterval, use [Client#guildMemberAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) to run only when someone joins.

eg.

```js
bannedID = ['123', '456']
client.on('guildguildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  // probably check guild with member.guild

  // if their ID is in the list
  if (bannedID.has(member.id) {
    // they were banned, so do something
  }
});
```

Comment: guildguildMemberAdd not working with my bot for no reason. I tried this before i posted this question

Comment: You need to enable [privileged intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)