# Discord Welcome Message DM

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Bot, which sends the user a message via DM when they join the server. However when somebody joins the server nothing happens

```
const { group } = require('console')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')

const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json', 'utf8'))

const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.send("Message!");
    console.log('Welcomemessage sent to' + client.user.tag);
});

client.login(config.token)
```

There is nothing in the console as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start with anything you need to check from [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers) that you had already [enabled `PRESENCE INTENT` & `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` from **Bot Settings**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhMqp.png)

*This is your code:*

```js
const { group } = require('console')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')

const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json', 'utf8'))


client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.send("Message!");
    console.log(`Welcome message sent to: ${member.user.tag}`);
});

client.login(config.token)
```

**Stay Safe.**