# Discord bot not getting all of the members

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make a command which tells me the total amount of users in the servers the bot is in. I searched on how to make it and found this:

```js
const users = await client.users.cache.size
```

But when I use it the bot tells me it's serving only one user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) is all of the User objects that have been cached at any point, mapped by their IDs.

I don't think there is a single method or property to get the total number of members of every server the bot is in. You could probably iterate over the [`guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) the client is currently handling and fetch the members instead.

The following should work:

```js
async function getTotalNumberOfMembers(client) {
  const guilds = client.guilds.cache;
  let numberOfMembers = 0;

  // resolves once members from every guild is fetched
  await Promise.all(
    guilds.map(async (guild) => {
      const members = await guild.members.fetch();
      numberOfMembers += members.size;
    }),
  );

  return numberOfMembers;
}

// ...

const total = await getTotalNumberOfMembers(client);
console.log(total);
```

*Edit:* Yes, you can also use the [`.memberCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) property:

```js
function getTotalNumberOfMembers(client) {
  const guilds = client.guilds.cache;
  let numberOfMembers = 0;

  guilds.each((guild) => {
    numberOfMembers += guild.memberCount;
  });

  return numberOfMembers;
}

const total = getTotalNumberOfMembers(client);
```

Comment: The number of members doesn't show as if it doesn't stop running and I got an error: Members didn't arrive in time.

Comment: What do you mean by "never sent" and by "members"?  Is there any error?

Comment: Yes the error is:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.

Comment: There is a memberCount property maybe we could use it in the loop.

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to enable the `"GUILD_MEMBERS"` intents. It may help how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559391/6126373

Comment: Yes, memberCount is even better, then you don't need to fetch ;) I've updated my answer with it.