# Problem in getting the total users of my discord.js bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

My Discord.js bot just got verified for the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent so I brought a feature back which shows the total users of the bot but it doesn't quite work as I intend it to.

[image: image example]

I am currently using the `{client.users.cache.size}` property to find the total users.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot not getting all of the members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855511/discord-bot-not-getting-all-of-the-members)

Comment: lemme check it out

Comment: yeah it does, thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote that post then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can use a simple line in v12

```js
${client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) => a + g.memberCount, 0)}
```