# Not properly retrieving number of bots and people

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a member counter, when I type `,member-count` it gives me the total number of members on the server at that time in an embed as the title. The fields are supposed to show the number of people on the server and the number of bots separately but they only show 0 for each and I don't know how to make them change values.

Here is the code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'member-count',
    async execute(Client, message, args, Discord) {
        const MembersInServer = message.guild.memberCount;
        var BotsInServer = 0;
        var PeopleInServer = 0;
        if(MembersInServer === message.author.bot){
            BotsInServer++
        }
        else if(MembersInServer === message.author.member) {
            PeopleInServer++
        }
        MemberEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle(`${message.guild.name} has ${MembersInServer} members in the server!`)
        .addFields(
            { name: "People in the server:", value: PeopleInServer },
            { name: "Bots in the server:", value: BotsInServer },
        )


        message.channel.send(MemberEmbed);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like:

```
const members = message.guild.members.cache;
let BotsInServer = members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size
let PeopleInServer = members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size
```

Keep in mind you need to have presence intent on [refer to this post to know how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: should I keep my const ```MembersInServer = message.guild.memberCount;``` and is there a dark mode on this site?

Comment: @MohidMushtaq sure

Comment: well it is now showing 1 instead of 0 but still not working

Comment: @MohidMushtaq Do you have presence intents on?

Comment: i dont even know what that is

Comment: @MohidMushtaq That means you don't have it on, please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica to know how to turn presence intent on

Comment: it is now on what do i do now?

Comment: @MohidMushtaq restart bot and try again

Comment: IT WORKS thanks so much for the help this is very useful, might want to say that in your answer tho