# my bot don't see event "guildMemberAdd" why?

Tags: discord.js, message, glitch-framework

he don't view new member and don't write on console "nouveau membre"

```
Client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member, guild) => {
  console.log("nouveau membre");

})
```

Comment: Do your other events emit? You *may* need to enable the guild members intent

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica) relate to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `SERVER_MEMBERS_INTENT` in order to receive the guildMemberAdd event.

If you have a verified bot then it needs whitelisting, if not then just go to your application and to the bot tab and toggle the server members intent