# Sending Messages to members on join

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hi I want to get the bot to send a direct/private message to new users that join the server. It is able to post a welcome message on a channel but it doesnt work when i does in in private messages.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '*';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot Démarré');
    bot.user.setActivity('Chill \'N Code (*help)', { type: 'WATCHING' });
    bot.user.setStatus('online');
})
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log(member.user.username + " a rejoint le serveur");
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("<EARLY_SUPPORTER:840512953928515595> Bienvenue " + member.user.username + " !")
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/Kbl451j.gif')
    .setDescription("__**Voici quelques informations utiles :**__")
    .addFields(
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: '<:channel:840513546416554045> **Règlement**', value: 'Nous T\'invitions à lire le [règlement](https://discord.com/channels/836947422122344448/836947422173200410/836962049484390449]', inline: false },
        { name: '<:add_reaction:840512848266657792> **Rôles**', value: 'Tu peux prendre tes rôles [ici](https://discord.com/channels/836947422122344448/836947422617141290/837022973830496286)', inline: false },
        { name: '<:moderation:840528469317517333> **Devenir Staff**', value: 'Tu peux devenir staff [ici](https://forms.gle/rGV26bZytcx5atG28)', inline: false },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Github', value: '[Github](https://github.com/chillncode)', inline: false },
        { name: 'Twitter', value: '[Twitter](https://twitter.com/ChillNCode1)', inline: false }
    )
    .setFooter('Chill \'N Code', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/836947422122344448/d27317d317a5b260d0365f6ca0da5455.png');
    member.send(embed);
    console.log("message envoyé");
})
```

Comment: What does _"but it doesnt work"_ mean?

Comment: it doesnt send private messages. I tried console.log("someting"); but it doesnt work. It seems like he don't detect the event

Comment: Have you enabled the member intents?

Comment: oh no thank you i forgot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the SERVER MEMBERS INTENT enabled in the Discord Developer Portal