# Welcome message using guildMemberAdd event doesn't work | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have been trying to make a welcome message using the `guildMemberAdd` event but it is not working. I have no error in my code and the console also show not a single error so I don't know how to fix it.
Here is the code:

Sorry if it isn't clear. If you guys don't understand what I am trying to do and how I'll send my GitHub.

Thanks!

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = (client, member) => {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setDescription(`Welcome ${member.displayName} to the server!`)
        .setThumbnail(member.avatarURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true, size: 128 }))
        .setFooter(`User ID: ${member.id}`)
        .setTimestamp();

    client.channels.cache.get("846084493184860172").send(embed);
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure You Have These Two Boxed Ticked You Can Find Them in The Developer Portal in the Bot Section

[image]

Comment: Hey.I ticked on the 2 box you told me to but its still not working sadly...Any other ideas on how to fix it please?