# Caching users on discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot with discord.js and whenever I run this command it sets the user cache as 3-4. But with 74 servers it was around 700 users but not its at 3-4 how can I fix this using caching? I'm relatively new to .js developing and need help.

```
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
console.log(`Watching ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers!`)
console.log(`Watching ${client.users.cache.size} users!`)
console.log(`Watching ${client.channels.cache.size} channels!`)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: 3-4 is number of users you want to cache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried enabling the `Privileged Intents`?

To do this, you have to go to the **[Developer Portal](https://discord.com/login?redirect_to=%2Fdevelopers%2Fapplications)**. You'll then have to navigate to `Privileged Gateway Intents` in the **Bot** section and you'll have to activate these:

[image: Privileged Gateway Intents]

However, it is that simple only if your bot is **not** yet more than in **100 servers**. But as soon as you reach this mark of 100 servers and you need to **verify** your bot / or it **already is**, you have to **[request the activation.](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412)**

Hope this will help you out :)

---

#### References

- [Gateway Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)

Comment: The buttons are greyed out and when I hover over them they give me a not allowed sign.

Comment: Yeah, as I already said, you have to [request the activation](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412)

Comment: Is your bot verified?

Comment: No... I'm 15, tf am I supposed to do now? I have never travelled, don't have a passport, id or anything to prove who I am.

Comment: And what does this has to do with your question? :D