# Welcome message is not displayed on join for user in discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently making a discord bot using a node.js and I found a problem when I make welcome message.

This is the code :

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
    let chx = db.get(`welchannel_${member.guild.id}`);
    if (chx === null)
        return;
    let data = await canva.welcome(member, { link: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f3/1c/39/f31c39d56512dc8fbf30f9d0fb3ee9d3.jpg" })

    const attachment = new discord.MessageAttachment(data, "welcome-image.png");

  client.channels.cache.get(chx).send("Welcome to our Server " + member.user.username, attachment);
});
```

If I run them, nothing happens when a member joins the server.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica/64559391#64559391) to learn more about privileged intents

Comment: No errors either?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://discord.com/developers/applications and select your application go to the bot tab and scroll down to Privileged Gateway Intents and enable Server Members Intent, that should fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @Patriot said about setting up your bot registration with Discord, You also need to set up the intent when you make the Client.

An easy way to do this is

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({intents:Discord.Intents.ALL});
```

[More here on this if you want to be more specific in requesting intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)

Comment: Instead of adding onto an answer in another answer, edit the original answer.