# add role if member has invite in custom status

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want my bot to give a member a role if they have the servers invite in their status. Does anyone know how I could do that? maybe you could fetch the members info or something? I tried searching on google but I found nothing.
Thank you so much:)

Comment: What you'll need to check is `<member>.presence.activities`.  Try checking the docs for that [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities) and make some code before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Getting the custom status

As Squiddleton said, you can use the [`.activities`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities) property of `Presence` to get their a user's custom status. This property is an array of `Activity`s and you can get the custom status by finding the activity whose [`.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity?scrollTo=type) is `CUSTOM_STATUS`.

The activity of a custom status looks something like this:

```js
Activity {
  name: 'Custom Status',
  type: 'CUSTOM_STATUS',
  url: null,
  details: null,
  state: 'this is the status message',
  applicationID: null,
  timestamps: null,
  party: null,
  assets: null,
  syncID: undefined,
  flags: ActivityFlags { bitfield: 0 },
  emoji: null,
  createdTimestamp: 1625478958735
}
```

As you can see, the status message is stored in the `state` property.

```js
/**
 * The custom status message of `member`,
 * or `undefined` if the member does not have a custom status.
 * @type {string | undefined}
 */
const customStatus = member.presence.activites
  .find(activity => activity.type === 'CUSTOM_STATUS')
  ?.state
```

### Checking if the status includes the invite

You can use the [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to test if a string contains another string:

```js
const inviteLink = 'https://discord.gg/blahblah'

if (customStatus) {
  /**
   * Whether `customStatus` has the invite link `inviteLink`.
   * @type {boolean}
   */
  const hasInviteLink = customStatus.includes(inviteLink)
}
```

If you wanted, you could take this a step further and test if the custom status contains *any* invite from the server using a combination of [`Guild#fetchInvites`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchInvites) and the [`inviteCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-inviteCreate) client event.

### Adding the role

Now all you need to do is [add the role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) for that member:

```js
if (hasInviteLink) {
  member.roles.add(theRoleYouWantToAdd)
    // Don't forget to handle errors!
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

`theRoleYouWantToAdd` can be a `Role` or the ID of the role.

### Where do I put this code?

Discord.js has a [`presenceUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) event, which fires when a member's presence (such as their custom status) updates. Note that you need to enable the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent to receive this event (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559391/8289918) for more information).

The final code might look something like this:

```js
const roleID = // ...
const inviteLink = // ...

client.on('presenceUpdate', (_oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  const member = newPresence.member
  if (member) {
    // Ignore members who already have the role
    if (!member.roles.cache.has(roleID)) {
      const customStatus = newPresence.activites
        .find(activity => activity.type === 'CUSTOM_STATUS')
        ?.state
      if (customStatus) {
        if (customStatus.includes(inviteLink)) {
          member.roles.add(roleID)
            .catch(console.error)
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: wow thank you so much. I didnt need it all coded for me but still thank you very much:)

Comment: it says  ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined```

Comment: @Jan Hmm, according to the docs `member.presence.activities` should never be `undefined`. Where is this error occurring?