# Discord.JS: Welcome message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

At this moment I am trying to figure out why my 'Welcoming Message' isn't working at my own Discord server. I have been looking at several `Stackoverflow` topics and YouTube tutorials, I have read through the `Discord.js` documentation but I wasn't able to a proper solution. So, therefore I am trying to get my answers on this network via this topic.

The code I have so far:

```
client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
    let channelToSend;
    guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
        if(
            channel.type === "text" && 
            !channelToSend && 
            channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")
        ) channelToSend = channel;
    });
    
    if(!channelToSend) return;

    let channelEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RED")
    .setAuthor(`TEXT TEXT ${guild.name} TEXT!`)
    .setDescription("TEXT TEXT")
    .addField("Roles", "TEXT TEXT")

    channelToSend.send(channelEmbed).catch(e =>{
        if (e) {
            return;
        }});
})
```

I have absolutely no clue anymore why this isn't working. I also admit that I made the transition from `Python` to `Javascript` a month ago, so maybe I made an error somewhere?

I hope someone is able to help me out because I am clueless at the moment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you getting an actual error?

Comment: The guild is probably uncached. Use `guild.channels.fetch` instead

Comment: Do you have [intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica/64559391#64559391) enabled?

Comment: Wait, you are saying your problem is with the welcoming message, but what do you exactly mean? Like is it the message for the Bot joining a Server or is it the message for a Member joining the server?

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the help. It is extremely appreciated. @Lioness100: About the error, I am not getting any errors in my terminal or in my discord channel. There is no message at all (also not the expected embed).

Comment: @RishiMath About the error, I am not getting any errors in my terminal or in my discord channel. There is no message at all (also not the expected embed).

Comment: @RishiC : I tried to edit it but without any luck.

Comment: @Tyler2P Yes sir, I got it activated.

Comment: I meant to ask, like was the message supposed to be for when the bot joins a server? Or it is for when a member joins a server?
Since the guildCreate event is emitted when the bot joins a particular server.

Comment: @RishiMath Again, thank you for your quick reply. The message is supposed for everyone who joins the server. So, basically, I should change the guildCreate event? The code below written by Nigelrex actually works but I am still figuring out why, probably because of the 'guildMemberAdd' event?

Comment: Yeah, that is what it looks like in this case

Comment: It makes sense now I am reading through this. Thank you so much for the support @RishiMath and others! It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) =>
  client.channels.cache.get("789830758331318273").send({
  //put your channel id in replace of "789830758331318273"
    embed: {
      title: "Joined",
      description: `\n <@${member.id}> joined the server. There are now \`${member.guild.memberCount}\` in the server \nWelcome <@${member.id}> :wave:`,
      color: config.color,
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your code actually works. I am still wondering what I am doing wrong with my own code? Why isn't that working, probably because of the client.channels.cache.get("1234..") in your code? Again thank you so much for helping out. It is much appreciated.

Comment: @OrangeTiger if this code is producing then you were listening for the Wrong, since guildCreate event is Emitted when a bot joins a server, and guildMemberAdd event is Emitted when a new Member joins a server.