# server-info command not showing human and bots members discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a server info command and i want it to say how many humans and bots are in the server, here's the part of the embed that should do that:

```
{ name: 'Human members: ', value: message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size, inline: true}, 
{ name: 'Bots members: ', value: message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).size, inline: true},
```

But this is what i get: [image]

I'm trying the command in a server with like 50 humans and 10 bots, i hope you can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch the members before you check the cache. [`members.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) will fetch members from Discord, even if they're offline. It returns a collection of `GuildMember` objects so you don't even need the `cache` property any more:

```js
let members = await message.guild.members.fetch()

// ...
.addFields(
  { name: 'Human members: ', value: members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size, inline: true}, 
  { name: 'Bots members: ', value: members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size, inline: true},  
)
```

Comment: I'm using module.exports and stuff, and i tried putting async before execute(message, args), but the command doesn't work entirely, and vs code gives no error

Comment: So is it `async execute(message, args) {...` now? Have you tried to check what the value of `members` is?

Comment: Yes execute is now like that, but i haven't tried checking `members` value

Comment: Any update on this? Have you logged `members`? Have you found the problem? I tried it with my bot and it worked fine. Have you enabled `GUILD_MEMBERS` intents?