# Discord.js get all current guild online member usernames

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using the current latest version of Discord.js 12.5.3 and tried several different approaches for different versions.

In the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) I can see there are two args, first of which is "client" and the second one is simply "data", it's not specified which data it needs so it's a bit weird being the first time building a Discord bot.

I've tried to use the first arg only with this code:

```
bot.on("message", async (msg) => {
  if (!isCommand(msg) || msg.author.bot) return;

  const guild = new Discord.Guild(bot);
  console.log(guild);

});
```

Then I get this:

```
<ref *1> Guild {
  members: GuildMemberManager {
    cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
    cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    guild: [Circular *1]
  },
  channels: GuildChannelManager {
    cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
    cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    guild: [Circular *1]
  },
  roles: RoleManager {
    cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
    cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    guild: [Circular *1]
  },
  presences: PresenceManager {
    cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
    cache: Collection(0) [Map] {}
  },
  voiceStates: VoiceStateManager {
    cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
    cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    guild: [Circular *1]
  },
  deleted: false
}
```

Then I try `console.log(guild.members);`

and I get

```
<ref *1> GuildMemberManager {
  cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
  cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
  guild: <ref *2> Guild {
    members: [Circular *1],
    channels: GuildChannelManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
      guild: [Circular *2]
    },
    roles: RoleManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
      guild: [Circular *2]
    },
    presences: PresenceManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection(0) [Map] {}
    },
    voiceStates: VoiceStateManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
      guild: [Circular *2]
    },
    deleted: false
  }
}
```

in which cache is a `Collection(0) [Map] {}`

and `console.log(guild.members.guild.members);`

gives the same output than `console.log(guild.members);`

All code chunks marked as working are from older versions or not working to me.

I was guessing if I need to login the bot on another place but as long as message reply works... Here's the code for reference:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client({ disableMentions: "everyone" });
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

bot.login(process.env.token);

// event handlers
bot.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ready!");
});

bot.on("message", async (msg) => {
  if (!isCommand(msg) || msg.author.bot) return;

  /* 
  // get guild online member usernames
  
  const guild = new Discord.Guild(bot);
  console.log(guild.members);
   */

  msg.reply(handle(msg.content, msg.author.username));
});
```

Can you put me in the right direction about how to reach this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I've found that I need to enable **Privileged Gateway Intents** in Discord developer portal -> bot.

Then set up the bot like this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client({ disableMentions: "everyone", ws: { Intents: ["GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_PRESENCES"] } });
```

and finally I'm able to get online guild users that are not bots with this

```
bot.on("message", async (msg) => {
  if (!isCommand(msg) || msg.author.bot) return;

  let {
    guild: { members },
  } = msg;

  let allMembers = await members.fetch();
  let onlineUsers = allMembers.filter((member) => member.presence.status !== "offline");
  let availableUsers = onlineUsers.filter((member) => !member.user.bot);
  let usernames = availableUsers.map((member) => member.displayName);

  console.log(usernames);

  msg.reply(handle(msg.content, msg.author.username));
});
```

So it was about permissions and a little tweak. This is not linked or advertised in Discord.js documentation so it was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current server you're sending the message in from the `message` itself. [`message.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) returns the `guild` the message was sent in.

`guild` has a `members` prop that returns a manager of the members belonging to this guild. To get all the members, you can use the [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method that returns a promise and resolves to a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of members. Collections have a [`map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) methods that you can use to create an array of usernames.

Checking if a user is online is a bit trickier. You can check their [`presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=presence). Its [`status`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=status) prop can be `online`, `idle`, `offline`, or `dnd`. You can `filter` the array you created above and only return ones where the status is not `offline`.

Something like this should work:

```js
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
  if (!isCommand(msg) || msg.author.bot) return;

  let { guild: { members } } = msg;
  let allMembers = await members.fetch();
  let onlineUsers = allMembers.filter((member) => member.presence.status !== 'offline');
  let usernames = onlineUsers.map((member) => member.displayName);

  // array of usernames of users who are not offline
  console.log(usernames);
});
```

Comment: Yes it should but for any reason I can't catch at this point, the fetch method throws a timeout with this exact code and with other implementations I've tried so far.
\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:317
        reject(new Error('GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT'));
               ^

Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.

Comment: Yep, that's because of the missing `GUILD_MEMBERS` intents. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica/64559391#64559391

Comment: yup that's what I'd find out