# Getting all member of a guild

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to do this to get all users (with a specific role) of a particular guild.

I have this, but the terminal says that "member is undefined". Any help is really appreciated.

```
var members;
const guild = client.guilds.fetch(process.env.GUILD_ID)
console.log(guild)
guild.then(()=>{
guild.members.fetch()
})
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517258/discord-js-get-all-current-guild-online-member-usernames

Answer (score 0):

`client.guilds.fetch` will return a promise, not a value

You can modify `then` to get a guild response

```
const guildRequest = client.guilds.fetch(process.env.GUILD_ID)
const memberRequest = guildRequest.then((guild)=>{
  return guild.members.fetch()
})
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I did that and this is an error that is shown.

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Comment: I think it's expecting another promise return, could you do like this? `return guild.members.fetch()` @JeremyNguyen

Comment: Hi! I did add the "return", but it still presents the same error

Comment: Hmm I think it's related to discord.js particularly, could you share the whole function? @JeremyNguyen

Comment: Another possibility is that your guild is not existing, it will cause `send` undefined @JeremyNguyen

Comment: Yes sir,

import { Client, Intents } from "discord.js";
import { CLinkedList, Node } from "./LinkedList";
const DiscordJS = require("discord.js")
require("dotenv").config()

//Creating the bot
const client = new DiscordJS.Client({ 
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS]
});

const guildRequest = client.guilds.fetch(process.env.GUILD_ID)
guildRequest.then((guild)=>{
  return guild.members.fetch()
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("The bot is ready")
})

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

Comment: Oh, I see, though when I console.log(guild), it does display somethings

Comment: what was the response there? @JeremyNguyen

Comment: It was just displaying some information regarding the guild. That's all. "members" does not have anything.

Comment: I think you don't need to call `guild.members.fetch()`, just return `guild.members`. You can check [this implementation](https://github.com/sizzlorox/Idle-RPG-Bot/blob/526c2518be325aa3d775e1d983d7b5cd9f40d74d/idle-rpg/v2/DiscordBot.js#L68)

Comment: I just did it and console.log() it, it outputs guild.members as "undefined"

Comment: I think you've not populated `members` properly @JeremyNguyen

Comment: What does populate members mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243848/discussion-between-nick-vu-and-jeremy-nguyen).

Comment: what else do you have in `guild` data? @JeremyNguyen

Comment: I have the same problem. No matter I added `Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS` flags or enabled Privileged Gateway Intents (`GUILD_PRESENCES` and `GUILD_MEMBERS`), the `guild.members` object is still undefined.

Comment: my `guild` OAuth2Guild object contains `id`, `name`, `icon`, `features`, `owner` and `permissions`, but does not have `members`.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet@Raptor

Comment: The link Raptor shared earlier is useful, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517258/discord-js-get-all-current-guild-online-member-usernames) out @JeremyNguyen