# List all users in a role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was working on some code where if I was to do `!list <role>` (not a mentioned role), it would send an embed listing all users with that role. This is my code but every time I run the command it sends the embed but doesn't list the users in the role.

Code:

```
  const roleName = args.slice(1).join(" ");

  const userswithrole = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => { 
       message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === roleName)}).map(member => { 
         return member.user;
})
      

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Users with ${roleName} role`)
      .setDescription(`${userswithrole.join('\n')}`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setFooter(`${message.author.username}`, message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic:true }))

  return message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: Your lambda in the `filter` is wrong. The filter method takes lambda that return `bool` values like `filter(member => member.roleName === roleName)` or `filter(member => { return member.roleName === roleName; })`

Comment: Also, the `find` method does not return a bool but it returns the object that matches the provided condition.

Comment: Oh okay Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think you'll need remove the first argument (`args.slice(1)`) as the `args` array doesn't include the command.

Second, `userswithrole` is a mess at the moment, the `filter` doesn't do anything.

It would be easier to create a new `role` variable, check if a role exits with the entered name at all and if not, return an error. If there is a role with that name, you can filter the `members.cache` and check if the `member.roles.cache.has(role.id)`. It will return a collection of members, you can use the `.array()` method to convert it to an array and `join()` them by a newline as you did in your example.

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const roleName = args.join(' ');
  const roles = await message.guild.roles.fetch();
  const role = roles.cache.find(
    (r) => r.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase(),
  );
  if (!role)
    return message.channel.send(
      `**Error:** ${roleName} is not a valid role on this server`,
    );
  const members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
  const usersWithRole = members.filter((member) =>
    member.roles.cache.has(role.id),
  );

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Users with ${roleName} role`)
    .setDescription(`${usersWithRole.array().join('\n')}`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setFooter(
      `${message.author.username}`,
      message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
    );

  return message.channel.send(embed);
});
```

[image]

If you don't want the user's to be mentioned, you can use the `map() method to get their` displayName` instead:

```js
const usersWithRole = members.filter((member) =>
  member.roles.cache.has(role.id),
).map(member => member.displayName);
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you. But the command seems to not be working everytime I do it, it comes back with the embed but not actually listing the users. Sometimes it'll work but other times it'll just show nothing in the description part of the embed. Is there any solution to that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Maybe the members are not cached, I've just updated my answer above. Could you test it again? Thanks

Comment: looks like the command reads the message if the role is wrong and reply's with the error message but it doesn't send the users in an embed, neither does it give an error message in the terminal.

Comment: Looks like now it gives an error message, it is: ```Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.```

Comment: That means `GUILD_MEMBERS` intents are not enabled. Check out this post to enable them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica/64559391#64559391

Comment: Wow, perfect works now. Thank You so much!

Comment: This is akward, both of our answers work according to the OP haha.

Answer (score 1):

A [Role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) has a [members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members) property which holds it's *cached* members who have this role.

For commands like these it's best to fetch all GuildMembers first for most accuracy. You will need to enable the GuildMember's intent for fetching to work.

This example will use async/await, ensure to make your function async otherwise use callbacks

```js
try {
   await message.guild.members.fetch();
   const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === roleName);
   const usersWithRole = role.members.map(m => `${m.user.username}`)
      .join('\n');

   // Embed work here
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Works, Thank You !

Comment: Click the green checkmark on the left if my solution is correct :v