# Discord.js Import Intents

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been really frustrated about this new Discord.js update. It includes importing Intents, and I have no idea how to do that. Please can someone tell me a step by step guide?

I have tried enabling all Intents from the Discord Developer Portal, still doesn't work. I would be very grateful if someone could help me! :)

Comment: Check out the [upgrade guide from V12 to V13](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is straight from the [discord.js V13 Docs](https://deploy-preview-551--discordjs-guide.netlify.app/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents)

e.g.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const myIntents = new Intents();
myIntents.add('GUILD_PRESENCES', 'GUILD_MEMBERS');

const client = new Client({ ws: { intents: myIntents } });
```

read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559391/10926046)

Answer (score 0):

You can find this from the discordjs docs > https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents

```
const { Client, Intents, Message } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
     intents: 32767,
});
```

32767 Means all intents. If you want to use the intents you want to use it is in the docs.