# Role Count not working properly discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I tried doing a role count for a specific role with a role ID. My problem now is that the count isn't working properly. I gave 4 people the role and the bot is only counting one person with that role and I don't know why.

My Code:

```js
case 'new':
   let roleID = "877984124483400480";
   let membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID).members;
   message.channel.send(`There are ${membersWithRole.size} People with the new Group on our discord`)
break;
```

Comment: Try fetching all the members

Comment: Can you show me where to fetch the members? I don't really understand what to do

Comment: Before declaring `membersWithRole`, use `await message.guild.members.fetch()`

Comment: I tried that but now it's giving me an error after a while. `Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend fetching it because cache is unreliable.

```
case 'new':
   let roleID = "877984124483400480";
   const rolesCache = await message.guild.roles.cache.fetch()
   let membersWithRole(roleID).members;
   message.channel.send(`There are ${membersWithRole.size} People with the new Group on our discord`)
break;
```

Or it can be the intents. Check if you have server members intents and have `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent in the client options.