# Discord.js v12 guildMemberAdd doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {

  console.log("mudda")
 fs.readFile('welcomemessage.txt', 'utf8' , (err, welcomemessage) => {
   if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
   }
   //code here
    fs.readFile('welcomemessagechannel.txt', 'utf8' , (err, welcomechannel) => {
     if (err) {
     console.error(err)
     return
     }
     const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === welcomechannel)
     channel.send(welcomemessage)
   })
   //code welcomemessage
  
  })
 //code event


})
```

It doesnt seem to work so well, so i dont know if its a bug or not

Could please help me.

Thank you very much

Comment: What does _"It doesnt seem to work so well"_ mean? Is there any error? Do you see `"mudda"` in your console?

Comment: By "doesn't seem to work so well" do you mean the event doesn't emit at all or the procedure executed in the event doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559391/12879643) It might solve your problem

Comment: You could be missing intents

Answer (score -1):

Try this
In your code
`client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {`
Change to

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
```