# discord.js return GuildMember undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a problem when I define "member" like that:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('my guild id')
const member = guild.members.cache.get('the member id that I need')
```

When I use it, I can't get its properties because the console tells me that it is undefined.
So what's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to make sure that you've enabled the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent on the [Discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers) in your application. After you've done that you need to include the intent in the `Client`.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]});
```

After you've done this, it should work. If it doesn't work, the member isn't fetched or the user is not in the specified guild. If the member is in your server you need to fetch the user by using the `fetch` function. The `fetch` function will return a `Promise` which will return the `GuildMember` if the `Promise` is fullfilled. If the `Promise` is rejected, the member is not in your server or there was an error while trying to access the member. You can fetch the user in this way:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]});

client.once('ready', async () => {
    var guild = client.guilds.cache.get('The Guild ID');
    if(!guild){
        try {
            guild = await client.guilds.fetch('The Guild ID');
        } catch (error) {
            return console.log(`Error while fetching the guild: `, error);
        }
    }
    var member = guild.members.cache.get('The User ID');
    if(!member){
        try {
            member = await guild.members.fetch(`The User ID`);
        } catch (error) {
            return console.log(`Error while fetching the member: `, error);
        }
    }
});

client.login('Your token');
```